# jQuery pass dynamic element id/value into PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I want to pass the dynamicLi element id and text into the PHP which look like this.

```
<ul id ='dynamicUL'>
    <li id='dynamicLi'><div id="fieldname">Field 1</div></li>
    <li id='dynamicLi'><div id="fieldname">Field 2</div></li>
    <li id='dynamicLi'><div id="fieldname">Field 3</div></li>
</ul>
```

The dynamicLi and the fieldname is generate from  database through PHP and jQuery, and therefore do not have a fix number.

What method should I use to pass this fieldname id and text (Field 1, 2, 3) into PHP? Using array, json or xml? And how should I do it using jQuery?

thank you.

Comment: Before going any further, remember that id's must be unique on a page, there for the <div id="fieldname"> should in-fact be <div id="fieldname-1"> then fieldname-2 and so on..

Comment: How is it generated exactly? I'm confused with "generate from database through PHP and jQuery".

Comment: I use jQuery to get the database table field name, save in the array with JSON then pass to jQuery and append it in the "dyanmicLi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can see my answer working here:** http://jsfiddle.net/kq2uQ/

**HTML**
I added numbers at the end of the dynamicLi because you IDs need to be unique on a page.
I also added a wrapper

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id ='dynamicUL'>
        <li id='dynamicLi1'><div id="fieldname">Field 1</div></li>
        <li id='dynamicLi2'><div id="fieldname">Field 2</div></li>
        <li id='dynamicLi3'><div id="fieldname">Field 3</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var unordered_lists = $("#wrapper ul");

    $.each (unordered_lists, function(i, list) {
        var list_elements = $(list).children("li");
        var list_id = { data: [] }

        $.each (list_elements, function(i, element) {
           var id = $(element).attr("id");
           list_id.data[i] = id;
        });

        //alert(list_id.data);
        $.post("/path/to/file.php", list_id.data);
    });

});
```

Comment: can you show me your 'file.php'? need some guide.
thank you :D.

Comment: what do you need to do on your php side?

Comment: So if I pass the list_id.data into the php, how do I use php to read the list_id.data?

While for the php, actually i want to pass the text(Field 1, Field 2, Field 3) to php to create the SELECT query to the database. 

example: SELECT "Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3" FROM TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to submit the values to a php script. the values can be in any format, preferably json.